# Lock one of two fragments in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I have two navigation fragments in the DrawerLayout. One navigation fragment in on the left and second is on the right.

In some cases I need to open left navigation fragment and lock it.

When I had only left navigation fragment I used             `drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);`
But when I have added second navigation fragment on the right, this method started to open and lock both panels.

How to open and lock only left navigation view in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Change you code like this

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout); 
  mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  mLeftDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
  mRightDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close) {

    public void onDrawerOpened(View view){
      if(view.equals(mRightDrawerList)) { 
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, mLeftDrawerList); 
      } else { 
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, mRightDrawerList);
      } 
      invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
    } 

    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) { 
      if(view.equals(mRightDrawerList)) { 
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, mLeftDrawerList); 
      } else { 
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, mRightDrawerList); 
      }
      invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
  });

  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: How to use above code if I am using FragmentDrawer using fragments in XML :-
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer_right"
        android:name="fragment.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer_left"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer_left" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>